# Trying to find a proper regression model for non-negative dependent variable

Tags: regression, distributions, multiple-regression, python

I'm trying to build a regression model predicting passenger numbers on trains using a number of different variables. Originally my plan was just to do a linear regression, but the issue is the model sometimes returns negative dependent values, which of course makes no sense in the context of passengers. I'm trying to figure out another way to build a good model / another type of distribution that would make sense here, but I'm struggling to find an alternative so any help would be appreciated! I'm using stats model and scipy for what it's worth in Python. I've thought about a Poisson or Gamma distribution but am not sure if those are valid here.

Also, for what it's worth, I'm pretty sure this comes from me training the model with mostly high-volume flights. So for lower volume flights it assumes we can have negative values since it is linear

Comment: Poisson is a good start, but I imagine there might be over dispersion in which case you should then try a negative binomial.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a good fitting regression model, a few 'negative passenger' results are not a problem, in my opinion, as one always just cap a large fall (or increase) prediction.

In fact, if your explanatory variables are actually explaining passenger ridership levels, this is, from a modelling perspective, a possible positive as it may correctly delineate (at least approximately near the mean) the negative impact of changes (like in, for example, # of trains running in rush hour). A decrease in service could precipitate (with a lag effect) a possible loss in total ridership as riders opt-out of trains and just drive their car, or via the internet, engage in carpooling arrangements. A large increase in train fairs, without any correlated relative increase of cost for driving/parking may similarly suggest loss of passengers, except for the most loyal (irrational) passengers (hence, support for capping). A large decrease in ticket prices may similarly suggest very large increases in ridership (again unlikely consider capping, as people are not easily inclined to give-up their cars).

Linear models and their forecasts, at times, are best be viewed as approximations from a more complex reality. They can be informatively useful, but should not be considered as absolutes, especially in regions far from the mean.